# SageMaker Estimator.fit() didn't pass the 'train' input to the Training instance

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

As in the documentation / tutorial mentioned, we can call `Estimator.fit()` to start Training Job.

Required parameter for the method would be the `inputs` that is s3 / file reference to the Training File. Example:

```
estimator.fit({'train':'s3://my-bucket/training_data})
```

**training-script.py**

```
parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'])
```

I would expect `os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN']` to be the S3 path. But instead, it returns `/opt/ml/input/data/train`.

Anyone know why?

**Update**

I also tried to call estimator.fit('s3://my-bucket/training_data'). 
And somehow training instance didn't get the SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN Environment Variables. In fact, I didn't see the s3 URI in Environment Variables at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running training jobs in SageMaker the S3 URL containing your training data provided ends up being copied into the docker container (aka training job) from the specified url. Thus the environment variable SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN is pointing to the local path of the training data that was copied from the S3 URL provided.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateTrainingJob.html#SageMaker-CreateTrainingJob-request-InputDataConfig

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your argument `os.environ['SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN']` doesn't give a path with the `s3://` prefix on it, if you are expecting it to pull the data from s3. Without that prefix, it instead searches its own local file system in the image for that path instead.

Comment: But as you can see in my code calling the `fit()` method, I already provide a valid s3 file path... Isn't that the right way to provide the train argument?